# Empty list of figures with multitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, multitoc

I have a document using `multitoc` and the list of figures is always empty.

The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

A figure:

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics{figure.jpg}
    \caption{Figure}\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces a document with an empty list of figures. Commenting out

```
\usepackage{multitoc}
```

produces a document with a working list of figures.

According to the documentation `multitoc` should work with list of figures. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If my answer solves you problem, please keep the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, it does. And thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `[lof]` when loading the package `multitoc`:

```
\usepackage[lof]{multitoc}
```

Your example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[lof]{multitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
A figure:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics{example-image.jpg}
    \caption{Figure}\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

yields the following output (run LaTeX twice!):

[image]